# Conversion to AutoCAD layer name changing - hyphen to underscore symbol

Tags: arcmap, autocad

Shape or feature class multiple layers export to drawing file layer name changing (wherever using - hyphen symbol and space changing to underscore symbol)

Is there any way same layer name convert to CAD drawing?
Is there any way same symbology convert to CAD drawing?

Comment: A hyphen isn't a valid character for table or column names in ArcGIS . This is very common (and part of the SQL stanard). Case insensitivity is also common.

Comment: What version of AutoCAD? ETL Tools can do this. ESRI notes what Vince mentions https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005588

Comment: Vence, Mapperz Thanks for the support. Am using Autodesk Civil3d 2022